# Select specific area from a matrix with R

Tags: r, image-processing

I have computed and image in R, and I have defined certain pixels as 0, I only want the "0" that are completely surrounded by pixels with quantities ranging:

```
inpixno0 <- filter(inx0, inx0$pixel!=0)
range(inpixno0$pixel)
# [1] 0.5000476 0.6998763`
```

For example, I only want the black area surrounded by the red area.

[image]

I have created a data frame containing the pixels mentioned and their indexes. It looks like this:

```
   > inx0[326:333,]
# row col     pixel
# 326  36  34 0.5141253
# 327  37  34 0.5039121
# 328  38  34 0.0000000
# 329  39  34 0.0000000
# 330  40  34 0.0000000
# 331  41  34 0.5376547
# 332  42  34 0.5866648
# 333  43  34 0.6188273

dim(inx0)
# [1] 12350     3
```

I have got a lot of these data frames, and my idea is to extract the row and col indexes for the values equal to 0 I am interested in and have a new data frame for every data frame that I have of these.

I like to know how it can be done with an efficient code so I can apply it to all the data frames that I have of these characteristics (over 1500).

Reproducible data set (500 observations only):

```
structure(list(row = c(87, 87, 92, 93, 94, 96, 101, 80, 91, 92, 
93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 102, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 
97, 98, 99, 100, 102, 104, 78, 80, 82, 83, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 
97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 79, 97, 98, 99, 
100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 102, 104, 105, 
106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 
113, 116, 108, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 54, 55, 56, 57, 
58, 59, 62, 112, 114, 115, 116, 117, 55, 56, 57, 58, 117, 53, 
54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 
56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 121, 122, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 
53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 122, 123, 124, 126, 44, 45, 46, 
47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 124, 125, 
126, 127, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 
55, 56, 125, 126, 127, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 
46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 
37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 
53, 54, 55, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 
42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 27, 28, 29, 
30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 
46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 
34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 
50, 145, 146, 147, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 
36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 49, 146, 25, 
26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 
42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 145, 146, 147, 23, 26, 27, 28, 29, 
30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 
46, 133, 145, 147, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 
34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 133, 134, 135, 150, 22, 
23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 
39, 40, 41, 51, 53, 62, 63, 64, 77, 134, 135, 136, 150, 151, 
23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 
39, 40, 41, 52, 53, 60, 62, 65, 83, 84, 135, 136, 137, 150, 151, 
152, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 
37, 38, 39, 49, 51, 52, 53), col = c(13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 
14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 
16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 
17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 
18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 
19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 21, 
21, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 23, 
23, 23, 23, 23, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 25, 25, 25, 25, 
25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 26, 26, 26, 26, 
26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 
27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 
27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 
28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 
29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 
30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 
30, 30, 30, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 
31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 32, 32, 32, 
32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 
32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 
33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 
33, 33, 33, 33, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 
34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 35, 35, 35, 
35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 
35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 
36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 
36, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 
37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 
38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 
38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 
39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 
39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40), pixel = c(0.692499524081477, 
0.695745288406624, 0.694355606320198, 0.699857224443175, 0.692061679040548, 
0.688235294117647, 0.696363982486199, 0.693023034456501, 0.686645726251666, 
0.686769465067581, 0.691909385113268, 0.686398248619836, 0.683447553778793, 
0.682352941176471, 0.675623453264802, 0.678555111364934, 0.680392156862745, 
0.696449647820293, 0.698781648581763, 0.693318103940605, 0.695878545592994, 
0.684751570531125, 0.667628022082619, 0.665705311250714, 0.679392727964972, 
0.687235865219874, 0.65221778031601, 0.66082238720731, 0.69564058633162, 
0.695478774033885, 0.666542927850752, 0.694669712545212, 0.685722444317533, 
0.693565581572435, 0.69776318294308, 0.683761660003807, 0.687074052922141, 
0.676470588235294, 0.675889967637541, 0.683704549781079, 0.67843137254902, 
0.645040928992958, 0.666666666666667, 0.674538359032933, 0.683761660003807, 
0.662440510184657, 0.66749476489625, 0.67395773843518, 0.696354464115744, 
0.696906529602132, 0.684161431562916, 0.680192271083191, 0.68913953931087, 
0.695926137445269, 0.67365315058062, 0.664705882352941, 0.671844660194175, 
0.675414049114791, 0.685522558537979, 0.680944222349134, 0.688235294117647, 
0.681496287835522, 0.679840091376357, 0.688939653531315, 0.686274509803922, 
0.665810013325719, 0.696935084713497, 0.662745098039216, 0.671692366266895, 
0.665134209023415, 0.66317342470969, 0.695402627070246, 0.699552636588616, 
0.694060536836093, 0.658319055777651, 0.664258518941558, 0.677089282314869, 
0.67848848277175, 0.685208452312963, 0.697087378640777, 0.690700552065487, 
0.699495526365886, 0.699562154959071, 0.68271463925376, 0.682352941176471, 
0.697096897011231, 0.681772320578717, 0.696659051970303, 0.69499333714068, 
0.6954121454407, 0.69804873405673, 0.689548829240434, 0.699352750809062, 
0.696078431372549, 0.686931277365315, 0.697363411383971, 0.696040357890728, 
0.690196078431373, 0.677136874167143, 0.657490957548067, 0.686255473063011, 
0.662250142775557, 0.676708547496669, 0.68063011612412, 0.695821435370265, 
0.699743003997716, 0.688577955454026, 0.688235294117647, 0.651104130972778, 
0.6613744526937, 0.670930896630497, 0.679706834189987, 0.693993908242908, 
0.690538739767752, 0.681343993908242, 0.650856653340947, 0.666162193032553, 
0.651361126975062, 0.640481629545022, 0.66324957167333, 0.655473063011612, 
0.653826384922901, 0.661345897582336, 0.678117266324005, 0.668056348753094, 
0.662678469446032, 0.672168284789644, 0.693232438606511, 0.688301922710831, 
0.68026841804683, 0.695117075956596, 0.619760137064534, 0.631448695983247, 
0.595155149438416, 0.605035217970683, 0.612726061298306, 0.598191509613554, 
0.636217399581192, 0.64594517418618, 0.657900247477632, 0.643099181420141, 
0.664667808871121, 0.676660955644393, 0.677317723205787, 0.670702455739577, 
0.696078431372549, 0.694079573577004, 0.694193794022463, 0.693194365124691, 
0.687312012183514, 0.638749286122216, 0.619493622691795, 0.573586521987436, 
0.562859318484676, 0.555939463163906, 0.58927279649724, 0.597344374643061, 
0.619493622691795, 0.644060536836094, 0.646135541595279, 0.629525985151342, 
0.655939463163906, 0.681429659242338, 0.671397296782791, 0.679240434037693, 
0.694698267656577, 0.694346087949743, 0.664011041309728, 0.698039215686274, 
0.693080144679231, 0.668846373500857, 0.629944793451361, 0.578964401294499, 
0.541442984960975, 0.532438606510566, 0.536093660765277, 0.547058823529412, 
0.580972777460498, 0.603074433656958, 0.645050447363412, 0.631639063392347, 
0.667780316009899, 0.659137635636779, 0.682667047401484, 0.672549019607843, 
0.687654673519894, 0.67843137254902, 0.661897963068723, 0.654835332191128, 
0.663801637159717, 0.684951456310678, 0.634941937940225, 0.678012564249, 
0.652807919284217, 0.624367028364745, 0.605044736341138, 0.516105082809823, 
0.565343613173423, 0.538663620788119, 0.511897963068724, 0.579973348562726, 
0.614563106796117, 0.626965543498952, 0.641947458595088, 0.633333333333333, 
0.673320007614696, 0.67556634304207, 0.693413287645156, 0.674186179326099, 
0.681781838949172, 0.686521987435751, 0.676146963639825, 0.615810013325719, 
0.623653150580621, 0.614667808871121, 0.630801446792309, 0.632467161621931, 
0.626556253569389, 0.633009708737864, 0.609680182752713, 0.5368075385494, 
0.529735389301352, 0.538397106415382, 0.56294498381877, 0.618465638682657, 
0.614296592423377, 0.641871311631449, 0.622834570721493, 0.657062630877594, 
0.662050256996002, 0.674833428517038, 0.68468494193794, 0.689053873976775, 
0.682038834951455, 0.643755948981534, 0.651599086236436, 0.659956215495907, 
0.671825623453265, 0.643137254901961, 0.597211117456691, 0.579259470778603, 
0.602884066247857, 0.604330858557014, 0.607947839329907, 0.6, 
0.570797639444128, 0.580696744717303, 0.545821435370265, 0.536017513801637, 
0.578745478774035, 0.606396344945745, 0.625899486007995, 0.621463925375975, 
0.651085094231868, 0.694327051208834, 0.691538168665525, 0.682762231106034, 
0.684827717494765, 0.698239101465828, 0.669712545212259, 0.691614315629165, 
0.627117837426232, 0.625823339044356, 0.614391776127928, 0.636169807728917, 
0.622777460498763, 0.605672948791168, 0.580934703978679, 0.57592804111936, 
0.590405482581381, 0.594450790024748, 0.56145059965734, 0.546183133447553, 
0.525823339044356, 0.528869217589949, 0.539758233390443, 0.573091566723777, 
0.603921568627451, 0.61927470017133, 0.633999619265183, 0.642804111936036, 
0.699581191699982, 0.691614315629165, 0.689862935465448, 0.687692747001713, 
0.691823719779173, 0.681420140871883, 0.651818008756901, 0.664144298496097, 
0.623063011612412, 0.603455168475157, 0.603359984770607, 0.620074243289549, 
0.612231106034647, 0.566009899105273, 0.559385113268609, 0.550980392156863, 
0.576936988387588, 0.553788311441082, 0, 0, 0, 0.540243670283648, 
0.609242337711784, 0.617180658671236, 0.618208642680373, 0.649952408147725, 
0.657053112507139, 0.683380925185608, 0.687492861222159, 0.696544831524843, 
0.695612031220255, 0.669931467732724, 0.68458975823339, 0.685884256615268, 
0.661593375214165, 0.659984770607271, 0.654901960784314, 0.603150580620599, 
0.57998286693318, 0.571749476489624, 0.589015800494955, 0.593346659051971, 
0.543137254901961, 0.507433847325337, 0.514125261755188, 0.503912050256995, 
0, 0, 0, 0.537654673519894, 0.586664762992576, 0.618827336759947, 
0.643156291642872, 0.641566723776889, 0.662354844850562, 0.6694079573577, 
0.689015800494955, 0.683932990671998, 0.688777841233584, 0.665257947839328, 
0.638587473824482, 0.617494764896247, 0.590196078431373, 0.566590519703026, 
0.575061869407956, 0.587921187892633, 0.569017704169047, 0.527450980392157, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.503997715591092, 0.581724728726442, 0.628545592994481, 
0.61152674662098, 0.630192271083193, 0.670350276032745, 0.680468303826386, 
0.655682467161624, 0.695526365886162, 0.683133447553781, 0.697020750047591, 
0.695840472111176, 0.695069484104321, 0.65638682657529, 0.640995621549591, 
0.620083761660004, 0.592156862745098, 0.566190748143918, 0.536541024176661, 
0.560308395202741, 0.544146202170189, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.582114981915096, 
0.613725490196078, 0.617647058823529, 0.656148867313916, 0.676946506758043, 
0.655853797829811, 0.693165810013326, 0.698039215686274, 0.690434037692747, 
0.691680944222349, 0.686112697506187, 0.691024176660957, 0.691833238149629, 
0.655549209975252, 0.626803731201219, 0.594117647058824, 0.571235484485056, 
0.552132114981916, 0.528583666476298, 0.529411764705882, 0.50491147915477, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.507519512659433, 0.596887492861221, 0.613240053302875, 
0.610451170759565, 0.644269940986102, 0.672710831905578, 0.696402055968018, 
0.690357890729107, 0.685627260612984, 0.688397106415382, 0.69181420140872, 
0.68141062250143, 0.660955644393679, 0.66709499333714, 0.637426232628973, 
0.610317913573195, 0.60204644964782, 0.564534551684752, 0.518846373500854, 
0.502731772320577, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.583038263849227, 0.625318865410242, 
0.623529411764706, 0.660869979059585, 0.692670854749665, 0.698296211688558, 
0.690538739767751, 0.695059965733864, 0.692499524081476, 0.693356177422422, 
0.697867885018085, 0.674252807919285, 0.676556253569389, 0.669988577955456, 
0.686702836474395, 0.639367980201788, 0.672549019607843, 0.641252617551874, 
0.639187131163145, 0.607824100513992, 0.59600228440891, 0.537302493813059, 
0.525461640967067, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.551008947268227, 0.590177041690463, 
0.63720731010851, 0.668598895869027, 0.688206739006282, 0.694155720540643, 
0.68640776699029, 0.696040357890729, 0.688216257376737, 0.694155720540643, 
0.680468303826384, 0.68045878545593, 0.696078431372549, 0.676461069864839, 
0.692213972967827, 0.697934513611271, 0.68239101465829, 0.682381496287835, 
0.653141062250143, 0.645231296402056, 0.640643441842755, 0.617780316009899, 
0.596078431372549, 0.554968589377499, 0.534361317342469, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.527784123358082, 0.593851132686084, 0.630972777460498, 
0.665105653912051, 0.692156862745098, 0.692423377117838, 0.686541024176662, 
0.690329335617742)), .Names = c("row", "col", "pixel"), row.names = c(NA, 
500L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be a good use for the little used matrix indexing. Here is a simpler example:

```
> mat <- matrix(1:9, 3,3)
> mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
> mat[cbind(1:2, 3:2)]
[1] 7 5
```

It looks like you already have the rows and columns of the pixels you want, so it would be something like :

```
inpixno0[cbind(rows, cols)]
```

Comment: I want to select only the indexes of the 0's totally surrounded by none 0 values. I refer to the black area in the plot totally surrounded by red. (not the 0 points that are surrounded by red and white (pixels with different values that I do not have in the plot)

Comment: Did you go from matrix/image format to a long format using `reshape` or `melt`? In that case, you might use merge instead matrix indexing.

Comment: I took only one of the color layers (B) to work with. Because it had the information I was aiming for. On the Image, I used resize but that was the first step I took.